# Why video start buffing with offline server?

Tags: ios, buffering, gcdwebserver

I am doing the functionality of downloading video and playing in offline mode. Here I am using NexPlayer with GCDWebServer my videos are encoded and needs to sync with server. I am using GCDWebServer for offline mode but after some video play its starts buffering.

So my question is this is offline server and we already having all data so why its buffering, I am not getting this. Please suggest something or can I use any other server instate of GCDWebServer.

Comment: I missed that question at the time, but just for posterity, be sure to look at the Xcode output log when running your app. GCDWebServer when built in Debug configuration will log extensively telling you what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to late reply but I found the solution for my problem.
Actually I set some buffering values with NexPlayer as online video playing but as we have a file locally stored, we don't want any buffing values to interrupt the process.
So I just removed them, simply set to 0 and it works perfectly as per expectations. 
No buffing, happy life :)